# using <xsl :variable> to improve readabily

Tags: html, xml, xslt

i had a code

```
<xsl:template match = "WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq|CommlUmbrellaPolicyQuoteInqRq|CommlAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq|CommlPropertyPolicyQuoteInqRq|GeneralLiabilityPolicyQuoteInqRq|CrimePolicyQuoteInqRq" mode="generalOverview">
```

and i want to improve the readability in order to put all the values separated by OR (|) on a new line, i tried this

```
<xsl:variable name = "WorkComp" select = "WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:variable name = "Umb" select = "CommlUmbrellaPolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:variable name = "ComAuto" select = "CommlAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:variable name = "ComPol" select = "CommlPropertyPolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:variable name = "GenLia" select = "GeneralLiabilityPolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:variable name = "Crime" select = "CrimePolicyQuoteInqRq" />
    <xsl:template match = "$WorkComp"|"$Umb"|"$ComAuto"|"$ComPol"|"$GenLia"|"$Crime" mode="generalOverview">
```

but still it is not working , can anyone suggest me some better way.

Comment: First, your code is formatted incorrectly, there should be no spaces around the equals signs. Then, even if you could use variables in the `match` attribute, what makes you think you should or could end the string before having the `|`? That is part of the string, after all. I believe you can simply put newlines into the match string, though. Oh, and one more thing: When asking about XSLT, always note which version you are using, XSLT 2 is much more versatile, but not as widely supported.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig *" there should be no spaces around the equals signs."* Where do you get this from?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry, you’re right – those spaces are perfectly legal. It is just a very widely followed style guideline and my memory confused that with a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a variable in the `match` attribute of `xsl:template`. However you can still achieve your goal of "improve the readability in order to put all the values separated by OR (|) on a new line" by:

```
<xsl:template match="WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq |
                     CommlUmbrellaPolicyQuoteInqRq |
                     CommlAutoPolicyQuoteInqRq |
                     CommlPropertyPolicyQuoteInqRq |
                     GeneralLiabilityPolicyQuoteInqRq |
                     CrimePolicyQuoteInqRq" 
               mode="generalOverview">
```

--
P.S. To improve readability even further, consider commenting your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of elements which appear to be different kinds of "PolicyQuoteInqRq", and you are applying similar processing to each. You might like to consider using a schema-aware transformation with XSLT 2.0. This would allow you to define all these different kinds of "PolicyQuoteInqRq" as members of a substitution group, perhaps headed by an abstract element named "PolicyQuoteInqRq", and then you would be able to replace your match pattern with

```
match="schema-element(PolicyQuoteInqRq)"
```

If this saves you a lot of duplication throughout the stylesheet, it could well be worthwhile, and it will make the code easier to modify (or even better, unnecessary to modify!) when new kinds of policy are introduced.